# regex catastrophic backtracking ; extracting words starts with capital before the specific word

Tags: python, regex, backtracking

I'm relatively new to Python world and having trouble with regex.

I'm trying to extract Firm's name before the word 'sale(s)' (or Sale(s)).

I found that Firm's names in my text data are all start with capital letter(and the other parts can be lowercase or uppercase or numbers or '-' or ', for example 'Abc Def' or 'ABC DEF' or just 'ABC' or 'Abc'),

and some of them are taking forms like ('Abc ***and*** Def' or 'Abc ***&*** Def').

For example,

from the text,

> ;;;;;PRINCIPAL CUSTOMERS In fiscal 2005, the Company derived
>   approximately 21% ($4,782,852) of its consolidated revenues from
>   continuing operations from direct transactions with Kmart Corporation.
>   Sales of Computer products was good. However, Computer's Parts and Display
>   Segment sale has been decreasing.

I only want to extract 'Computer's Parts and Display Segment'.

So I tried to create a regex

```
((?:(?:[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\-0-9\']*\.?\s?(?:and |\& )?)+)+?(?:[S|s]ales?\s))
```

(
1.[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z-0-9\']*.?\s => this part is to find words start with capital letter and other parts are composed of a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or - or ' or .  .

2. (?:and |\& )? => this part is to match word with and or & )

However, at https://regex101.com/ it calls out catastrophic backtracking and I read some related articles, but still cannot find way to solve this problem.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: `(?<=However,\s)[\S\s]+(?=sale)`

Comment: `re.search(r'((([A-Z][\w\']*|and|&)\s+)+)[sS]ale(s?)', s).groups()[0]` → `"Computer's Parts and Display Segment "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Overview

Pointing out a few things in your pattern:

- `[a-zA-Z\-0-9\']` You don't need to escape `'` here. Also, you can just place `-` at the start or end of the set and you won't need to escape it.
- `\&` The ampersand character doesn't need to be escaped.
- `[S|s]` Says to match either `S`, `|`, or `s`, thus you could potentially match `|ales`. The correct way to write this is `[Ss]`.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/rmxocj/3)

```
(?:(?:[A-Z][\w'-]*|and) +)+(?=[sS]ales?)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

> ;;;;;PRINCIPAL CUSTOMERS In fiscal 2005, the Company derived approximately 21% ($4,782,852) of its consolidated revenues from continuing operations from direct transactions with Kmart Corporation. Sales of Computer products was good. However, Computer's Parts and Display Segment sale has been decreasing.

#### Output

```
Computer's Parts and Display Segment
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:(?:[A-Z][\w'-]*|and) +)+` Match this one or more times

  - `(?:[A-Z][\w'-]*|and)` Match either of the following

    - `[A-Z][\w'-]*` Match any uppercase ASCII character, followed by any number of word characters, apostrophes `'` or hyphens `-`
    - `and` Match this literally
  - `+` Match one or more spaces
- `(?=[sS]ales?)` Positive lookahead ensuring any of the words `sale`, `Sale`, `sales`, or `Sales` follows

Comment: Thanks for your amazing regex!! Hope you have a day!! . Ah, by the way, I have to deal with millions of sentences and this regex seems to slow down a little bit when it applied to longer sentence. Is there any method that you would like to recommend to improve the speed of processing?

Comment: @ChanKim what might be faster in your instance is to split your string on `\s*[sS]ales?` and the use `(?:(?:\b[A-Z][\w'-]*|and) +)+$`, but you'd have to try it as I'm not sure it'll improve speed. It really depends on the input, how many occurrences exist, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment! I really appreciate!!